# Microsoft Graph - test existence of a file in a folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Given a file name, and the id of a folder, is there a resource url that I can use to see if the file exists in the folder? Something like /me/drive/items/{parent-id}/{name} seems logical.

Right now I am doing /me/drive/items/{parent-id}/children and searching through the resulting array which work. But hey.

thanks

Comment: I seem to be able to do /me/drive/items/{parent-id}/search. Is that restricted to {parent-id}, or does it include all folders underneath {parent-id}?

Answer (score 2):

The following queries work with the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) without any authentication. In the demo data provided by Microsoft, there is a file with the name 'Sales by Category.xlsx' within a subfolder 'Business Data'. Here are options to check, if that file exists:

1. Search the entire drive:

`GET:`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='Sales by Category.xlsx')
```

2. Search within a specific folder across all subfolder by using the subfolder id:

`GET:`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01BYE5RZ5MYLM2SMX75ZBIPQZIHT6OAYPB/search(q='Sales by Category.xlsx')
```

3. Search within a specific folder across all subfolders by using the relativ path:

`GET:`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Business%20Data:/search(q='Sales by Category.xlsx')
```

4. Directly access the file via Graph by using the relative path

`GET:`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Business%20Data/Sales%20by%20Category.xlsx
```

If you want to search only within a specific subfolder of a folder, you need to specify the folder prior to the search expression by using either the item id notation, the relative path or a combination of both. Subfolders are searched by default.
Option 4 is intuitive and seems to be faster, but it will throw a 404 error, if the item is not found. The Azure Admin may not like this, since this should show up in their logs. The search options will not throw an error and only return an empty result. So, searching may be better.

Comment: This works for me:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{parent}:/filename